# Layout inflation 3 times slower on Nexus 5X compared to older Nexus 5

Tags: android, performance, layout

I've noticed that inflation of a certain layout of mine takes up to 3 times longer on a Nexus 5X (Oreo 8.1.0) compared to an older Nexus 5 (Marshmallow 6.0.1).

The layout looks like below. As indicated half the layout is actually marked as `GONE` until the user clicks and then it gets shown. However, the measured layout times are without revealing the "gone" part of the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ImageView/>
        <Space></Space>
        <ImageView/>
        <Space></Space>
        <ImageView/>
        <Space></Space>
        <ImageView/>
        <Space></Space>
        <ImageView/>
        <Space></Space>
        <ImageView/>
        <Space></Space>
        <ImageView/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View/>
    <View/>
    <LinearLayout>                     <---- marked as .GONE   !!!
        <LinearLayout>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <ImageButton/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <Space></Space>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <ImageButton/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <Space></Space>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <ImageButton/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <Space></Space>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                <ImageButton/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <TextView/>
            <Space></Space>
            <TextView/>
            <Space></Space>
            <TextView/>
            <Space></Space>
            <TextView/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using the Profiler I get the following:

***Nexus 5***

`RecyclerView.OnCreateViewHolder` takes ~19ms

and measuring only the creation of the

`TextView` takes ~1.2ms

while

***Nexus 5X***

`RecyclerView.OnCreateViewHolder` takes ~60ms

`TextView` takes ~4ms

I've attached screenshots from the Profiler.

***My question is: Can I do something about this?***

I've tried converting it all to ConstraintLayout - then it gets even worse!

EDIT:

I should mention that the `RecyclerView` is embedded in a `ViewPager` and the reason for my concern is obviously that it takes so long to instantiate the ViewHolders (7 of them) on Nexus 5X that the user experiences this as the UI blocking.

Other project related info:

> minSdkVersion 23
>
> targetSdkVersion 28

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

[image: Nexus 5 - OnCreateViewHolder]

[image: Nexus 5x - OnCreateViewHolder]

[image: Nexus 5 - Create TextView]

[image: Nexus 5x - Create TextView]

Comment: how many holders do you have to create for your `RecyclerView`? less then 10?

Comment: Nexus 5: 6 ViewHolders are created and on 5x it's: 7 ViewHolders. PS: I've just made an edit to clarify the context a bit.

Comment: so cannot you `inflate()` those 6 views ahead and use some `Pools.SimplePool` or any other similar container in `onCreateViewHolder`?

Comment: The RecyclerView already does this itself. I'm not sure how it would work to pool across ViewPages so to speak. And it also doesn't really shed any light on why a never device with never OS is 3 times slower :-)

Comment: i mean create physical views before using your `RecyclerView` - that way your `onCreateViewHolder` will be as fast as a thunder, and for speed: if you are using the same support libraries, you can compare `LayoutInflater` sources (API 6.0 vs API 8.1) but i wouldnt expect any major differences - so there is really not much you can do with it

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks!! :-)